# TailwindCSS styles not applying correctly unless I use the Tailwind CDN file (Laravel 9.x/Tailwind 3.x)

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, laravel-9

I have installed a fresh version of Laravel 9.x (9.2 to be exact) with the Laravel Breeze starter kit for authentication. By default Laravel Breeze comes with Tailwind 3.x installed which is compiled in the following line inside the `<head>` HTML tags.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">`

Part of my view for some reason only renders correctly when I manually add the Tailwind CSS CDN file to the head like this in the `app.blade.php` file (obviously I'd prefer to NOT use the CDN file as Tailwind 3.x is already compiled within the app.css stylesheet).

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
  <!-- Really need to remove this line below -->
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.0.23"></script>
</head>
```

-- How it looks WITH the CDN link added to the head tag (this is how it should look like but without using the CDN) --
[image]
-- How it looks WITHOUT the CDN link added to the head tag --
[image]

Here is the code within my blade file (i've removed the Laravel PHP logic for simplicity and readability).

```
<tr style="display: none;" x-show="selected == {{ $loop->iteration }}">
    <td class="text-center text-xs" colspan="5">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
            <div class="basis-2/12">
                <div>
                    player123 | 9.3
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="basis-8/12">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 w-100 md:w-1/2 mx-auto border-b py-2">
                    <div class="text-center text-xs md:text-sm">10</div>
                    <div class="text-center text-xs md:text-sm">Shots on Target</div>
                    <div class="text-center text-xs md:text-sm">10</div>
                </div>                                                                                
            </div>

            <div class="basis-2/12">
                <div>
                    player721 | 9.3
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

-- Expected behaviour --

Have then stats 'row' displayed so it uses the full width of the table but without using the `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.0.23"></script>` tag (as illustrated in first image above).

-- Actual behaviour --

The stats 'row' has seemingly 'floated' to the left hand side of element - can anyone explain why the flex-row doesn't use the full width of the `<td>` container within the table?

p.s I am running npm run watch to auto build my app.css and I can see Tailwind 3.x stuff in the app.css file when I view source.

Comment: What's in the `content` array in the `tailwind.config.js`? I'd check to make sure that file is being referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot believe this - I had not run `npm run watch` that recreates the app.css - obviously tired.com

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem by adding the path for my vue components which i placed in resource for example: **resource/js/components/companies/CompanyIndex.vue** 
 adding this `'./resources/js/**/*.vue'` to content list in `tailwind.config.js` will solve the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `app.css`, try replacing:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

with:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

and run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` again.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Blade file located?  Laravel Breeze's default `tailwind.config.js` only looks in the following paths for discovery of the classes it needs to generate.

```
content: [
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
],
```